# jasmine-node runs only one spec file from 'spec' folder

Tags: node.js, express, jasmine, jasmine-node

I've written 3 spec files, each of them is designed for separate modules. The folder structure is:

```
|-spec
  |-module1.spec.js
  |-module2.spec.js
  |-module3.spec.js
```

Command  `jasmine-node --teamcity spec/` somehow runs only for the first `module1.spec.js` file and skips the rest files.

Could anyone explain what could cause such a behavior?

Comment: Not without seeing the conf file.

Comment: The documentation for [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) says nothing about some special configuration, the default is to `write the specifications for your code in *.js and *.coffee files in the spec/ directory.`

Comment: Looks like it is a known issue: https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/issues/378 (If you are the issue owner, please accept my apologies for referencing something you already knew about.)

Comment: Are you on Windows? (In other words, does that issue apply to you?) Other things to add to the info: if you rename the files so #2 is first, is it still skipped? Or is it run and the other two skipped? FWIW, I do not see this behavior.

Comment: @jakerella Yes, I use Windows and the behavior is the same if I rename files - all except the first spec are skipped

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: I've figured out what was causing the problem - every spec file initiated it's own `var app = express()`. The problem was that I've set `app.listen(8001);` to the same port for every spec. Changing different ports for each spec fixes the issue

Comment: Good to hear it's fixed! You should add an answer for your own question and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was causing the problem - every spec file initiated it's own `var app = express()`. The problem was that I've set `app.listen(8001);` to the same port for every spec. Changing different ports for each spec fixes the issue